# why does this only print hi once not ten times when i call for it to run ten times

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

i am trying to make a code that says hi in the console the console ten times,but it only prints once for some reason

```js
function a(){console.log("hi")
setTimeout(function(){ }, 1);
}
a(10);
```

Comment: What makes you think it would print ten times? May you explain through your reasoning?

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to give you a sophisticated answer.

With:

```
a(10);
```

your actually calling a function called `a` and since there is something in-between the brackets, you're also passing the value `10` to that function.

Now if we look at your definition for the function `a`:

```
function a(){
}
```

we can see that it doesn't accept any parameters because of the `()`.

That means the passed value 10 won't ever be used.

Furthermore, inside the function definition is this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ }, 1);
}
```

This actually delays the execution of the `function()` by one millisecond - but again - there isn't anything inside the function.
To summarize: you're just calling the `a` function once and the only thing that happens inside is logging `hi` to the console - one time.

Now I'm of course not sure what you're trying to accomplish but if you simply want to print something to the console ten times, a simple for-loop might do the trick:

```js
function a() {
  console.log("hi");
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a();
}
```

A more advanced example might even use the value passed to the function:

```js
function a(param) {
  for (var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
    console.log("hi");
  }
}

a(10);
```

Comment: No problem @codesforkids - I'm happy if I can help!